# Loop through php array with stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, stdclass

How do I loop through this array and get all the term_id's?

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [term_id] => 43
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [term_id] => 25
    )
)
```

Comment: `foreach ($arr as $item) { var_dump($item); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ob1 = new stdClass();
$ob1->term_id = 43;

$ob2 = new stdClass();
$ob2->term_id = 25;

$scope = array($ob1,$ob2);

foreach($scope as $o){
  echo $o->term_id.'<br/>';
}

// Out
// 43
// 25
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, that was what I wrote but I was outputting my code in in a select html element so I was looking in the wrong place haha, will accept in 4 min.

Answer (score 1):

Each element of your array is an regular object, so yo can access it just by `for` (if elements of array are in order and keys are integers) or `foreach` (in examples `$a` is given array):

For:

```
$count = sizeof($a);
for ($i = $count; $i--;)
{
    echo $a[$i]->term_id;
}
```

Foreach:

```
foreach ($a as $item)
{
    echo $item->term_id;
}
```

If you want to add all ids to another array, you just need to write following code (in example for foreach):

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($a as $item)
{
    $ids[] = $item->term_id;
}
```